# Unit Test equals() fails when comparing two Arrays

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, equals, sproutcore

The last Unit Test of in the following code fails, probably because the `==` operator, which is used by the `equals()`, doesn't compare the Arrays properly. However, I can't figure out why this happens.

Why does `equals()` fail when comparing an Array retrieved from an `SC.Record` to a newly instantiated Array?

**monster_model.js**

```
BagOfTricks.Monster = SC.Record.extend(
{
  name: SC.Record.attr(String, { defaultValue: 'Unspecified' }),
  level: SC.Record.attr(Number, { defaultValue: 0 }),
  keywords: SC.Record.attr(Array, { defaultValue: function() { return [ 'Unspecified' ] } })
}
);
```

**monster_test.js**

```
var defaultMonster;

module("BagOfTricks.Monster", {
    setup: function() {
        defaultMonster = BagOfTricks.store.createRecord( BagOfTricks.Monster, {} );
    },
    teardown: function() {
        BagOfTricks.store.reset();
    }
}
);

test("Default monster created as expected?", function() {
    equals(defaultMonster.get('name'), 'Unspecified');
    equals(defaultMonster.get('level'), 0);

    // The following test fails.
    var defaultKeywordArray = ['Unspecified'];
    equals(defaultKeywordArray, defaultMonster.get('keywords'));
}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript behaves quite strangely when it comes to comparing arrays. I can't tell you **why**, but I can tell you **how to avoid it**.

Use the **second** function from [Breaking Par: JavaScript Are Arrays Equal](http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256BFB0077DFFD).

It is type-safe and quite fast on large arrays.

Comment: I disagree with their premise that [ 'A', 'A', 'B' ] is equal to [ 'A', 'B', 'A'], but that's quite a good read. I'll see if that will work, if only at least for the Unit Tests.

Comment: It seems that 'Javascript behaves strangely' is the answer here, so thanks :) I won't be using the compare method you supplied for my current tests, but perhaps it will be useful later on.

Answer (score 0):

You need probably something like ArrayEquals (in Java) to check equals for all array "components".

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing

`keywords: SC.Record.attr(Array, { defaultValue: function() { return [ 'Unspecified' ] } })`

just do

`keywords: SC.Record.attr(Array, { defaultValue: [ 'Unspecified' ] })`

the first is causing a function to be returned when you do the `get` on the `keywords` property, not an array.

Comment: This would've been more of a comment on my question, instead of an answer. The first causes the returned function to be run and sets the array as a result. The second defines and initializes an array and sets it. I got warned against using the second approach, because that would cause every array changed as the defaultValue to be changed when I change only one of them (like some sort of class global).